# The record is not saved in the DJango-SQLite database

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django

I am trying to save a record in the database of a model (Score) that is related to two other models (User and Exercise), I receive the form correctly or so I think, and using the save() instruction does nothing. I don't even get errors.
Here the code:

**forms.py**

```
class ScoreForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #idUser = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), label='idUser')
    idExercise = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), label='idExercise')
    value = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), label='Value')

    class Meta:
        model = Score
        fields = ['idExercise', 'value']
```

**views.py**

```
def save_exercise(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax:
        form_score = ScoreForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form_score.is_valid():
            form_score.save()
        else:
            print('Tenemos un error')
    return HttpResponse('Respuesta')
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById('id_value').value = score;
document.getElementById('id_idExercise').value = idexer
// document.getElementById('id_idUser').value = iduser
let data = new FormData($('#scores').get(0));
        Swal.fire({
            title: '<strong>Tu resultado: </strong>',
            icon: 'success',
            html:              
                `<div class="progress"  style="height: 30px;"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" style="width:${number}%">${number}%</div></div>` +
                `Ganaste: ${score.toFixed(2)}`,
            focusConfirm: false,
            confirmButtonText:
                '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Okey!',
            preConfirm: () => {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/polls/save/",
                    data: data, 
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function(){
                        console.log('Funciona!')
                        show_exercise()
                    }
                 })
            }
        })
```

**In html file**

```
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
     <form method="POST" action="" novalidate id='scores'>
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form|crispy}}
     </form>
</div>
```

All the inputs of the form are type hidden since after a couple of calculations I assign their respective values, the form is sent from a modal using AJAX

I can't find an answer, since I don't know what error to look for, could you please help me

Comment: I guess this `request.is_ajax` to be a method and calling it  `request.is_ajax()`  should satisfy condition ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was the following, in the file views.py

```
def save_exercise(request):
    scr = Score.objects.filter(idExercise=request.POST['idExercise'], idUser=request.user)
    # print(serializers.serialize('json', scr))
    exer = Exercise.objects.get(id=request.POST['idExercise'])
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        if scr:
            scr.update(value=request.POST['value'])
        else:
            scr = Score(idUser=request.user, idExercise=exer, value=request.POST['value'])
            scr.save()
    return HttpResponse('Respuesta')
```

I was not taking into account the instances related to my Score model.